# How to find web elements by xpath when text of these are quotes?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, cucumber

I have a html displayed so:

```
|Character|Value|
|  comma  |  ,  |
|  dot    |  .  |
| quote   |  '  |
|doubQuote|  "  |
```

I have a method in java with the code below to verify if a web element contains a simple quote `'`
xpath by default is like this:
fields is an array where the characters `(; . ' ")` are

```
character = fields[i];
By.xpath("//div/span[contains(text(), '" + character + "')]");
```

when the test is running and use simple quote the xpath interprets the quote as if were a quote close and the xpath doesn't work.

I tried to use double quote in xpath but it would be the same problem when use the double quote character

The unique solution i found is create a condition only for `"` and `'` characters that is use simple quotes when the character to find is a double quote, and the inverse, use double quote when the character to find is a single quote

there is another idea to solve this?

Comment: You must also show the HTML source that produces the output. The rendered output is useless to understanding your issue.

Comment: It's a tricky one. There's no escape for single quote in xpath 1.0, which is what selenium is using.
I think your proposed solution is the way to go (except, your **only** special case is single quote, double quote follows the route of everything else)